# jQuery draggable browser scroll issue with helper:clone

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I've tried a million things here on Stack to fix this issue, Ive got divs with text within a div with content ID... Im making all divs with text draggable however as soon as I scroll the browser down, it screwed the position of the helper:clone element. Here's what I've got in my files;

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
$(document).ready(function($) {
  // let the .draggable items be draggable
  $( ".draggable" ).draggable({
    revert: "invalid",
    containment: "document",
    helper: "clone",
    cursor: "move",
    scroll: "false",
    refreshPositions: true
  });
```

It's not the overflow:scroll issue or anything, it just does this;

[image: the issue]

Comment: Can you make a fiddle plz?

Comment: I can't since its a full app, I just noticed the other day the issue within it.

Comment: anyone? I've been reading through Stack but nothing here seems to help the fact that helper:clone after page scroll puts the item in wrong position.